# Android: video returns to the beginning when device is rotated.

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have this activity that I use to play videos.

```
public class OtherActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
        VideoView view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); 
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http:somevideo.mp4"));  
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the problem here is that whenever I rotate the device the video goes back to the beginning. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is simply restarting when it rotates. This is default behavior of Android.

[Document yourself about android rotations and configChanges.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Answer (score 0):

To make a device rotation a configuration change add the following code to the `<activity>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Note: The device configuration is a set of characteristics that describe the current state of the device. The characteristics that make up the configuration include screen orientation, screen size, language and others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be happened on activity restart.

Please add below line in activity tag of AndroidMainfest.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
  ..........
  ..........
  </activity>
```

Comment: Why you are using extra parameter `keyboardHidden|keyboardHidden`? its not required in this scenario.

Comment: yeah you are correct but i copied this from my project,I m going to edit this.